Patch SSL_write with Frida
I tried to patch SSL_write with Frida
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("libssl.so", "SSL_write"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {

        let buf = "patch!!!";
        Memory.copy(ptr(args[1]), ptr(buf), 8);

    }
});

But I got
Error: expected a pointer

On Memory.copy  line

The frida script code you have written is executed in a JavaScript engine. JavaScript does not know pointers, and ptr only allows to "type cast" a variable to a pointer (e.g. an integer value).
Therefore if you want to access the pointer of a string you first have to allocate it in memory to get a pointer:
let strPtr = Memory.allocUtf8String("patch!!!")
Memory.copy(args[1], strPtr, 8);

Be aware that this command will fail if the buffer in args[1] is smaller than 8. Therefore I would recommend checking the buffer size first:
if (args[2].toInt32() >= 8) {
  let strPtr = Memory.allocUtf8String("patch!!!")
  Memory.copy(args[1], strPtr, 8);
}

Or if you simply want to replace the string argument it may be better to just overwrite args[1] with the pointer of the new string:
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("libssl.so", "SSL_write"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {

        const buf = Memory.allocUtf8String('patch!!!'); // allocate the string
        this.buf = buf; // Save it. Otherwise it will get freed by the garbage collector before it actually can be processed by the SSL_write implementation.
                        // This way it will be freed after the end of onLeave.        

        args[1] = buf; // replace args[1] with the new string
        args[2] = 8; // adapt the buffer size (expected by SSL_Write in this argument)
    }
});


By the way In that way to pointer buf will never free

@Polo1990 you mean because it is defined as const? As it is located inside a function it will be freed at the end of the function (no matter if it is const or not) but as it is saved to this this time is extended to the point where on leave has finished.

I checked you code and args[2] =8;  return Error:expected a pointer

@Polo1990 If Frida thinks args[2] should be a pointer even if according to the SSL_Write definition it is an size_t ( thus an integer) then simply assign ptr(8) to it. Frida should be satisfied and openssl will still interpret the value as integer.

thank you! That sounds like Frida bug. By the way this.buf = buf; save the pointer until the end of onLeave but maybe the program use that pointer to another thing? That will crashes the program. Or the program the the original pointer?

@Polo1990 Frida can not know the type of an args[?] entry. On assembler level everyzhing is just a CPU register and CPU registers don't have a type. The a buffer pointer is reused after the function has been executed is possible but rather unusual. Such special behavior would be mentioned in the documentation (if yo have access to it). If not you would need a decompiler like Ghidra/IDA to check how the pointer is used.

args[1][parseInt(args[2])]=0x02; does it should change the value of the last byte? I don't see that change?

@Polo1990 I don't think so because you are thinking again in C style but you are actually in JavaScript. Pointer arithmetics using arrays don't work in JavaScript. Use a NativePointer alias Ptr(..) and add for doing pointer arithmetics and in the end use  writeU8 instead to change a single byte. That is the Frida way you can use in JavaScript. https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#nativepointer
